# ubuntu just crashed when I login no desktop loads up

Tags: unity

Hi guys ubuntu has just crashed on me, what now happens is when I log in as the main user I get no desktop loades up just the desktop background ALSO I can't access my terminal using CTRL, ALT etc. What is weird is that if I login as the guest everything works. But I have all of my university work on my main login so I am really worried and would be very grateful for some help, thanks guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). Also you can look into [How do I reset my Unity configuration](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)